# call external api from within docker container

Tags: docker-compose, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm building a project which uses an api which will be running as a service or iisexpress (depends when running on windows, or linux)

while my dashboard application is running in a docker container.

If my dashboard is running in the container and my api is running from the exe(kestrel) than i'm not able to call my api.

I assume that it is because the internal docker network cannot find the host addresses?

what I have tried:

```
var result = new Host();
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = await client.GetAsync("http://192.168.0.196:5000/api/host");
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Host>(content);

            }
```

the ip address given is the host ip address of my computer, because i want to test it locally.

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  dashboard:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}dashboard
    container_name: Dashboard
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dashboard/Dockerfile
    ports:
    - "1433:1433"
```

docker -compose that currently maps 1433 for the database

How can I call an external api from within the container?